# Windows 7 Desktop Manager

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, dwm

when we drag a window to the side of the screen we get like a ripple effect, can we change that programaticaly?

Comment: change that effect to a custom one?

Comment: Probably a bad idea to change it.  It violates the Windows UI guidelines and the API for it is not available in the Windows 7 Toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

i can't be 100% certain, but i'm 99.9999% certain that effect is not under program control.

That is a feature of Windows which, at the very most, would be left as a user preference.

So the answer to your question is, "*No, you cannot change that programatically.*"